# text aligment of right labels of MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I can't find out how to change the text gravity of the right side labels of my MPAndroidChart.

[That's how it looks actual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raQbi.png) [image]

[This is what it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ngeb.png)[image]

How is that to be done?

Comment: see mpchart documentation at https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki.

Comment: I know this doc but couldn't find anything about it

Comment: using legend  methods you can aligntext   : https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Legend

Comment: Didn't use the legend. Seems like a workaround. Maybe there's a better way to do this?

Comment: Please upload your xml code for more info

Comment: it is not legends it is y-axis values.

Comment: yes, and I can't find any useful method on y-axis to align the text

Answer (score 0):

Write android:gravity="right" in TextView.

Comment: It's not a TextView

Comment: Could you post your layout for more info

Comment: There is no layout. It's part of the MPAndroidChart lib.

Answer (score 0):

Here is easy solution I came with, set Value formatter like this:

```
 chart.getAxisRight().setValueFormatter(new IAxisValueFormatter() {
    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
        return String.format("%7s" , value);
    }
});
```

It adds needed spaces in front of value.
In my case it is 7 (`"%7s"`), so if your value's length is less then 7 symbols, it will be filled with needed amount of spaces in front and here is result:

[image]

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late response. I tried it out and it's not working for me. I locat all Strings look fine. But not on the diagram: [see what happened](https://imgur.com/W7vkT0l)

Comment: @Mirco, It is really Y axis's values you want to format ? As you see it works on my screen. It would be good if you provide more code